# Angular limitTo filter, how to prevent Word wrap?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm using the angular limitTo filter to show less Text :

```
<body ng-app="m">
    <div ng-controller="c">
      <h1>angular</h1>
      <p ng-bind-html="desc | limitTo:22"></p>

    </div>
  </body>



// Angular application

var app = angular.module("m",['ngSanitize']);

app.controller("c",function($scope){

  $scope.desc = "this is a t&apos;est with special chars &quot;";

});
```

I want to avoid showing the html entities when they are truncated,

is there any filter to prevent word wrapping ?

Comment: Do you mean u dont want to include html entities like "quotes" not to include in  view when filtering ?

Comment: Could you show output example here what exactly you want to see?

Comment: do you mean like this  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap ?

Comment: Here is a plunker of what i mean : https://plnkr.co/edit/qg185nwJbWFiFiTugcTz  as you can see i don't want to have to word in the second line truncated

Comment: To double check, when you set limitTo:14, you want to see "this is a t'es"! am I right? 14 characters

Comment: Yes exaclty this is what i'm trying to do !

Comment: investigate $sce. Also you can replace html chars in your javascript.